# SELECT Query, WHERE selects all when "" is empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**The Aim**

Hi, I'm trying to shorten my code by building the query dynamically based on the $`_GET`. Current I have every possible If statement with the relevant `SELECT` query. However I would like to create a dynamic system for feature updates.

**Current Progress**

```
//Set Filter based on url
        if ($_GET[GAME] != "") { $gameFilter = $_GET[GAME]; } else { $gameFilter = ''; }
        if ($_GET[Region] != "") { $regionFilter = $_GET[Region]; } else { $regionFilter = ''; }
        if ($_GET[Console] != "") { $consoleFilter = $_GET[Console]; } else { $consoleFilter = ''; }

    $result = get_matchfinder($gameFilter, $regionFilter, $consoleFilter);
```

//The Function

```
function get_matchfinder($gameFilter, $regionFilter, $consoleFilter) {
        //Set Varibles
        $database = 'matchFinder';
        $order = 'DESC';
        $limit = '20';

    //Query Function
    $connection = connection();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM  '. $database .' WHERE game = "'.$gameFilter.'" AND region = "'.$regionFilter.'" AND console = "'.$consoleFilter.'" ORDER BY ID '. $order .' LIMIT '. $limit .'';
    $response = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);   

    //Return
    return $response;
}
```

**Problem**
Currenly it works when all of the filters are active but if one of them isn't the whole query fails, I know thats because it is try to SELECT something matching `''`.

So my questions is how do I make it search for all when that filters is not set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should build the query parts depending on the length of the filter:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT * FROM '.$database.'
';

$filters = array();
if (strlen($gameFilter) > 0) {
    $filters[] = 'game = "'.mysqli_escape_string($connection, $gameFilter).'"';
}
if (strlen($regionFilter) > 0) {
    $filters[] = 'region = "'.mysqli_escape_string($connection, $regionFilter).'"';
}
if (strlen($consoleFilter ) > 0) {
    $filters[] = 'console= "'.mysqli_escape_string($connection, $consoleFilter).'"';
}

if (count($filters) > 0) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $filters);
}

if (strlen($oder) > 0) {
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY ID '.$order;
}
if ($limit > 0) {
    $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$limit;
}

$response = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

What you're doing there is building up an array of conditions, based on the length of the condition. If the condition's input is an empty string, it isn't added to the array. At the end, if there are any filters, use `implode` to bind the conditions into a string. The way `implode` works, if there's only one condition, the glue string isn't used.

It also bears mentioning that you are exposing yourself to SQL injection. The above code shows the use of `mysqli_escape_string` to escape the input, but you should look in to parameterized queries to take full precaution: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php -- the above sample would only be slightly different if you used paraterized queries, but significantly more safe.

**Documentation**

- `strlen` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php
- `implode` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
- Mysql parameterized queries - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Cheers for the in-depth explanation, I shall try it now :) And i will 100% look into fixing the sql injection, cheers

Comment: @MattHammond Using `mysqli_escape_string` as shown above is *okay* security, but clunky and easy to forget. You are using what is called the "procedural" mysqli functions. In a nutshell, this means "not an object." You'll see that the documentation shows using an object instead. It's a little bit of a shift, but once you get used to it you'll find it easier, and you won't have `mysqli_escape_string` calls all over the place in your code. Using the parameterized queries and the object, you don't even have to wrap values in quotes, it does that for you :) Good luck and happy learning :)

Comment: That sound so much simpler, I will be sure to have a look, always learn :) Thank you again for the in-depth explanation!

Comment: I've found an issue, it works when not filters are set however when using any filter nothing with show. the url looks like - http://domainname/MatcherJSON.php?GAME=BO3 - However without the ?GAME=BO3 it will show all the results so I know that part of the query isn't broken, any ideas? I've gone ahead and echod out the query and I'm getting this - SELECT * FROM matchFinder WHERE game = "" LIMIT 20

Comment: Its the escape string thats causing the problems

Comment: @MattHammond No, you *must* escape input from the URL. Otherwise, I could pass SQL on the query string and drop your whole database. The problem is case sensitivity -- if the parameter is "GAME=B03" then you must use `$_GET['GAME']` -- notice all-caps on the query string, all-caps in the variable.

Comment: I beg that, however it's breaking the query when it's used in its current state, can swapping it from the function and put it where it's setting the variables?

Comment: Check what the output of this is: `if ($_GET['GAME'] != "") { $gameFilter = $_GET['GAME']; } else { $gameFilter = ''; } die('gameFilter: '.$gameFilter);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112932/discussion-between-chris-baker-and-matt-hammond).

Comment: I will try it in about 30mins as I'm currently away from my Mac

Answer (score 2):

You would have to build your search dynamically

You could start your base query with

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM  '. $database .' WHERE 1=1'
```

Then, if $gameFilter!="", append to your existing $sql string with `"and game=$gameFilter"`

The syntax for appending would be like this

```
if ($gameFilter!="")
 {
    $sql.=' and game=$gameFitler'
 }
```

and so on checking for all of your search conditions.

Comment: I thought that, however with that way I'm getting stuck on appending it to the current query, please can you set an example of doing just that? Also what is the 1=1?

Comment: i added a simple appending string edit...the answer given by @Chris Baker seems to be more complete...

Comment: Ok I think i get you, so I have the start query then after the 1=1' I if each of the tiler?

Comment: @MattHammond If you take this approach, the "1=1" bit is a non-statement, that is, it doesn't affect the query. But, it lets you get the WHERE statement on the string, so later when you add conditions, the WHERE is already on the string. If you look at my example, I wait until the end and append WHERE only if there are conditions. Simply different approaches, but you should understand the difference and know why "1=1" is necessary here but not in my example. Both would work, simply a matter of preference in approach.

Answer (score 1):

Make you string like this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM  '. $database .' WHERE 1=1 {0} {1} {2}'

if ( $gameFilter <> '') 
    $sql = str_replace("{0}", "AND game = '".$gameFilter."'" , $sql);
else 
    $sql = str_replace("{0}", "" , $sql);

if ( $regionFilter <> '') 
    $sql = str_replace("{1}", "AND region = '".$regionFilter."'" , $sql);
else 
    $sql = str_replace("{1}", "" , $sql);

if ( $consoleFilter <> '') 
    $sql = str_replace("{2}", "AND console = '".$consoleFilter."'" , $sql);
else 
    $sql = str_replace("{2}", "" , $sql);
```

Comment: I get this error when i use your code, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in . and I'm not sure how to fix it. The line error refers to your first if

Comment: maybe didnt close with `;` previous sentence? or I miss the `if {}` I cant test php code, Im writing from memory to give you general idea